# Is there a way to have a derived state variable auto update when it's dependencies update?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a solution, whether that be a library or whatever to reduce the amount of times I have to write state variable useEffect updaters. I have a state var that is dependent on other state variables. The logic for the value of the variable will never change, so I want an alternative to writing useEffect with the variables dependencies and manually updating the value.

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  const [a, aSetter] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [b, bSetter] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const [someCustomState, someCustomStateSetter] = useState<boolean>(a && !b)
}
```

What I don't want

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    someCustomStateSetter(a && !b)
  }, [a, b])
```

I just want the single line initializing the state with the logic and any time `a` or `b` changes, so does `someCustomState`. Thanks!

Comment: Just use a derived value `const c = a && !b;`
 - there is no need to put that in a `useState`

Comment: Using state for values that are strictly derived from other state or props is an anit-pattern. It can only cause extra renders and allow an opening for bugs. Just calculate it each render. If the calculation is expensive (it almost never is) then use memoization to reduce the number of times you need to calculate it